# Angular2 parsing HTTP response

Tags: javascript, json, http, angular

I have modified the quickstart tutorial to get a collection of Posts from the following URL: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts, but I only see the default initialization values, not the actual values from the server.

One of the elements looks like:

```
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  }
```

This object is represented as a Post class defined below:

```js
export class Post
{
    userId: number;
    id: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
 }
```

The service returns an Observable of Post[]

```js
import { Post } from './post'

@Injectable()
export class PostService{
    private postUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    public getPosts (): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.postUrl)
                    .map(this.extractData);

    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
    }
```

And the Component subscribes to the Observable to obtain the array and set its attribute:

```js
import { Post } from './post'
import { PostService } from './postservice.service'

@Component({
    selector:'mi-comp',
    template: `<h1>Embedded Component</h1>

        <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
        {{post.id }}  {{post.title }} 
        </li>
        </ul>
    `,
    providers: [PostService]
})

export class MiComponente
{
    posts: Post[] =   

     [{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio            reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
  }];

    errorMessage: string;
    counter = 0;

    constructor(private postService: PostService){

    this.postService.getPosts()
                            .subscribe(
                            posts => this.posts = posts,
                            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);   
}
```

If I change the extract function of the service so as to return body.data, I see the default values for one second, and then empty. I have debugged the response and I can see the 100 element array there.

Additionally, if I change everything from Post to string, I can see a list of 100 objects on the screen.

Comment: Have you tried just returning `body` from `extractData`, rather than `body.data`? Looking [at the documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#parse-to-json) it does note that their server was set up to return the values in a data object, but that *"[n]ot all servers return an object with a data property."*

Comment: Yes, returning body instead of body.data did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

In `class MiComponente`, change to this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';
import { PostService } from './postservice.service'

@Component({
    selector:'mi-comp',
    template: `<h1>Embedded Component</h1>
        <ul *ngFor="let post of posts">
          <li>{{post.id }}</li>
          <li>{{post.title }}</li>
          <li>  {{post.body}} </li>
        </ul>`, 
    providers: [PostService]
})

export class MiComponente implements OnInit
{
    posts [];

    errorMessage: string;

    constructor(private postService: PostService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.postService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => this.posts = posts, error => this.errorMessage = error); 
    }
}
```

In `class PostService`, change to this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';  
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 

@Injectable()
export class PostService{
    private postUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    public getPosts (): Observable {
        return this.http.get(this.postUrl).map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }
}
```